# How to toggle one of many links with icons using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have several dynamically created links which rendered as buttons and the buttons texts are replaced with icons.  I need to toggle one of the link button icons when clicked.  The method that I am using is not working out.  See code below:  I do not want to use JQuery at this time unless it’s within a function.

```
    <a class="button" onclick="command('removeFormat');" title="Remove Format"><i class="fas fa-eraser"></i></a>
    <a class="button" onclick="command('fullScreen');" title="Full Screen"><i class="fas fa-expand"></i></a>
    <a class="button" onclick="doToggleView();" title="Source"><i class="fa fa-code"></i></a>
    <a class="button" onclick="submitForm();" title="Save"><i class="far fa-save"></i></a>
```

//JS

```
    function command(cmd){
      if(cmd == 'fullScreen'){
        $(".fa-expand").toggleClass('fa-expand fa-compress');
      }else{
        $(".fa-compress").toggleClass('fa-compress fa-expand');
      }
    }
```

I also try using the following codes:

```
    $("i").toggleClass('fa-compress fa-expand');
    $("a .button").find("i").toggleClass('fa-expand fa-compress');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the fix to resolve the issue.

```
    function command(cmd){
        $('i.fas').toggleClass('fa-expand fa-compress');
    }
```